# How to instantly stop the rotation of an object in BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I can't stop the rotation of the camera(around the z global axis), in BGE. The camera is set to dynamic. Here is part of the script, the only one that affects rotation.

```
def rotation():
    if (mX < 0.10) and (mY < 0.90):
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, 0.1], 0)
    elif (mX > 0.90) and (mY < 0.90):
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, -0.1], 0)
    else:       
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, -cam.getAngularVelocity().z], 0)
    #print (cam.position)
    print ("Angular Velocity :",cam.getAngularVelocity())
```

Setting the angular velocity to 0 does not work.So what I did was to subtract the current value(cam.getAngularVelocity().z). This kills the rotation but it is still slow and it creates a flickering effect.

I found 2 threads about this thing in other forums. They were unsolved. Any thoughts?

Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35807)

Comment: could you convert it to a static object?

Comment: I do not want to, since I would not be able to use velocity no more.What's on your mind though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [reported bug](https://developer.blender.org/T41943)

[Workaround](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-171727.html): use a very small value like `0.00000012`

```
def rotation():
    if (mX < 0.10) and (mY < 0.90):
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, 0.1], 0)
    elif (mX > 0.90) and (mY < 0.90):
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, -0.1], 0)
    else:       
        cam.setAngularVelocity([0, 0, 0.00000012], 0)
```

Comment: Many thanks! That was it. I think this bug is for linear velocity also, but I fixed it with what you suggested.